# generic Insertion sort can't sort floating point array

Tags: c

I've coded a generic version of **insertion** sort algorithm.  It works fine with int and char, but it can't sort floating-point numbers. I can't figure it out. Does it have to do something with the representation of floating-point numbers in memory or something else?

Here's my code:

```
void insertion_sort(void *array, int elemSize, int arrSize){
    for(int i = 0;i < arrSize;i++){
        for(int j = 1;j < arrSize;j++){
            void *elem1 = (char *) array + ((j-1) * elemSize); 
            void *elem2 = (char *) array + (j * elemSize);
            if(memcmp(elem2,elem1,elemSize) < 0){
                void *temp = malloc(sizeof(elemSize));
                memcpy(temp,elem1,elemSize);
                memcpy(elem1,elem2,elemSize);
                memcpy(elem2,temp,elemSize);
                free(temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
Sample output of insertion sort:
char:-)
Unsorted :      e d a c b
Sorted   :      a b c d e

int:-)
Unsorted :      4 5 2 3 1
Sorted   :      1 2 3 4 5

float:-(
Unsorted :      3.3 1.2 44.5 5.1 2.8
Sorted   :      44.5 2.8 3.3 5.1 1.2
```

Edit:
This code doesnt work with int or char either. Check out the other version i wrote here [link]: https://bitbucket.org/Kessinger/c-generics/src/master/generic_insertion_sort.c

Comment: consider pre-allocating `temp` outside the for loop, if you have some valid size, and delete likewise. Also a custom comparator of form `int (*compareFcn)(const void*, const void*)` would be required to sort _any_ data type.

Comment: `memcmp` compares one byte at a time, and stops at the first difference. So this code will only work for `int` types on a [big-endian system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). For the `int` test, try 400,500,200,300,100 to see if your system is big-endian. Most systems aren't.

Comment: @user3386109 my system is little endian, so i am able to sort int's

Comment: Did you try the unsorted values 400,500,200,300,100?

Comment: no its not working

Comment: Right. You can't compare `int` values greater than 127 using `memcmp`. The `int` test with 4,5,2,3,1 appears to work because only one of the bytes in each `int` is non-zero.

Comment: Look at the standard C [`qsort()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/qsort.html) function.  It takes a comparator function pointer argument so that you can compare values appropriately (including sorting into ascending or descending order).  You'll need to do the same to get sane results from your generic sort.  The comparator function argument isn't an accident, or because the standards people want to make life difficult; it's there to make the generic `qsort()` work correctly.

Comment: @Kessinger: Re “my system is little endian, so i am able to sort int's”: No, little-endian is bad for comparing `int` or `float` objects with `memcmp`.  When sorting, you want to sort by the most significant parts first. With little-endian, the least significant bytes are first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While OP's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60094501/4944425) is a step in the right direction there are still some issues to be addressed.

For instance, this line:

```
void *temp = malloc(sizeof(elemSize));
//                  ^^^^^^^
```

Will allocate the wrong number of bytes, if the element of the array are not `int`s (the type of `elemSize`).

The condition in the posted snippet

```
if (memcmp(elem2, elem1, elemSize) < 0) {
```

Which is wrong, as noted in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60088332/generic-insertion-sort-cant-sort-floating-point-array#comment106273747_60088332) section, has been replaced by a call to the (not shown) comparison function. To be consistent with the requirements of `qsort`, if we want to sort an array in ascending order, such function should return a negative integer value if the first argument is less than the second, a positive integer value if the first argument is greater than the second and zero if the arguments are equal. A trivial implementation, e.g. for `int` values could be the following:

```
int cmp_int(const void *lhs, const void *rhs)
{
    int a = *(int *)lhs;
    int b = *(int *)rhs;
    if (b < a) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (a < b) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Note that this customization point, could be exploited not only to generalize the sort function for different types, but also in terms of sorting direction (ascending or descending).

A minor detail (not an error, just an inefficiency) is that the inner loop is executed too many times (always from 1 to `arrSize`), not much of a difference for an O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm, but they are still double the times needed. A modified version of the function is shown below

```
typedef int (cmp_fn) (void const *, void const *);

void insertion_sort(size_t array_size, void *array,
                    size_t elem_size,
                    cmp_fn cmp)
{
    void *buf = malloc(elem_size);
    //                 ^^^^^^^^^
    for(size_t i = 1; i < array_size; ++i)
    {
        for(size_t j = i; j > 0;)
        { //           ^^^^^^^^^  
            void *b = (char *) array + (j * elem_size);
            void *a = (char *) array + (--j * elem_size);
            //                          ^^^
            if(cmp(a, b) == 1)
            {
                memcpy(buf, a, elem_size);
                memcpy(a, b, elem_size);
                memcpy(b, buf, elem_size);
            }
        }
    }
    free(buf);
}
```

**Edit**

The link added to the question also leads to this attempt to write a generic print function (comments mine):

```
void printArr(void *arr, int size, int elemSize) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        void *elem = (char *) arr + (i * elemSize);
        if(elemSize == sizeof(int)) {
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^            
            printf("%d ",*(int *)elem);
        } else if (elemSize == sizeof(double)) {
            //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      Note the type 
            printf("%1.1f ",*(float *)arr + (i *elemSize));
            //          ^     ^^^^^^^             Ops...
        } else if (elemSize == sizeof(char)) {
            printf("%c ",*(char *)elem);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Besides the type mismatch, using `elemSize` to determine the type of the array isn't a good idea, at least not very portable. For instance, while may be uncommon for an architecture to have `sizeof(int)` equal to `sizeof(char)`, it is quite common nowadays to have `sizeof(int)` equal to `sizeof(float)` and almost certainly `sizeof(float)` is less than `sizeof(double)`. This, also, cannot discern between `int` and `unsigned int`, but will use the same format specifier.

As an exercise, it could be interesting to implement the generic print function like the sort one, passing a pointer to a function responsible to print an element in the correct way.

It's worth noting that this method of achieving generalization requires the programmer to be extremely careful, expecially with the matching of the involved types, to avoid undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to write this function is to provide a comparator function for int,char and float like this:

> insertion_sort (void *arr, int elemSize, int arrSize, int (*cmp)(const
>   void *,const void *))

And change the ***if*** condition with :

> `if (cmp(elem2,elem1))`

Assuming cmp returns 1 if **elem2 < elem1**.

Also **temp** variable should be declared outside for loop and freed at the end.

**Insertion_sort** After above modification should look like this:

```
void insertion_sort(void *array, int elemSize, int arrSize, int (*cmp)(const void *,const void *)){
    void *temp = malloc(sizeof(elemSize));
    for(int i = 0;i < arrSize;i++){
        for(int j = 1;j < arrSize;j++){
            void *elem1 = (char *) array + ((j-1) * elemSize); 
            void *elem2 = (char *) array + (j * elemSize);
            if(cmp(elem2,elem1)){

                memcpy(temp,elem1,elemSize);
                memcpy(elem1,elem2,elemSize);
                memcpy(elem2,temp,elemSize);
            }
        }
    }
    free(temp);
}
```

Comment: The comparator function version is better, but this doesn't answer the question since it doesn't mention why the original code didn't work. Please edit the question instead to only contain the _actual code you are having trouble with_.